# Printing Bibliographie on only one page latex ieee style

Tags: bibliographies

I am writing an IEEE paper on latex. I got a problem on the bibliography. 
It is being printed on 3 pages while I think all the references can be printed on only one page. 
I am using the following code and I could not find a solution.

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran} 
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,CDC2014}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 3):

Which IEEE journal or conference is requiring that? And is your text single or double column?

Generally speaking, you can force the start of a new page (or column in the case of double column mode) before the bibliography with something like:

```
\newpage
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
```

However, there is no guarantee that a given bibliography is short enough to actually fit on a single page. This might be true in your case given that three pages are being used - implying that the middle page is completely full with references.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Indeed welcome to TeX.SE!